# How to add RichText editor to a page as component in HippoCMS?

Tags: ckeditor, rich-text-editor, hippocms

I'm creating some project using HippoCMS 10 and I need to add RichText editor as part of the page, so that customer can use it and fill something there. This editor must act exactly the same way as in Document Editor (customer can click Image button in toolbar and select image from ImagePicker dialog box).

Can't find anything about it in HippoCMS official documentation. I learned how to create custom plugins and how to integrate CKEditor into page separately, but for image picking, I need default behaviour as in Hippo.

How can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think your question was answered on the community group. The answer there was:

"it should be quite easy to have a CKEditor in the website.

However, it doesn't really make sense to me to have site visitors able to pick CMS documents and images from the site. The picker dialogs are designed to work inside the CMS only. You should be able to create your own picker dialog that can read from a REST service that exposes the images/documents.

I don't think it will be possible to reuse the CMS picker dialog in the site."

and

"your use case is fine, when I said "it doesn't really make sense", I was really referring to the technical limitations of the pickers. You should be able to achieve what you want with a custom dialog that plugs into a REST service though. Unfortunately there is no quick solution for this that I can think of."

Just adding this for future reference.